# CentOS Web Panel CWP Apache php scripts not working

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, php, webserver

I have installed centos web panel on my centos6 server, CWP on my HP Proliant G8 server. I installed it as localhost web server.
I put php.info script in public_html folder, and it doesn't work in browser. Server shows the default webpage when typing IP, and folders in public_html folder, images etc... When I type script path, I get this answer:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

After this, I found out on some forums online that my document root in httpd.conf isn't /home/user/public_html. So I changed httpd.conf. After that, I couldn't open phpmyadmin from CWP, and file manager also. Luckily, I had a backup of httpd.conf and I returned the old one. After all of this I found out where are log files. I found an error log in /usr/local/apache/logs. The error log for this was:

```
Wed Dec 10 13:13:12 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.24] SoftException in Application.cpp:221: File "/home/rastaman/public_html/info.php" is not in document root of Vhost "/usr/local/apache/htdocs"
[Wed Dec 10 13:13:12 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.24] Premature end of script headers: info.php
```

Before this was one error more:

```
[Wed Dec 10 12:41:43 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.24] SoftException in Application.cpp:404: Mismatch between target UID (99) and UID (502) of file "/home/rastaman/public_html/info.php"
```

Here is the script content:

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

I don't know which apache configuration file is valid for me, and how it works with CWP (how can I see files and folders in public_html via IP address, but can't see the script, if apache is ok?), and what would be the solution for my problem. Other resources told me that the problem is that my Server API is command line interface, and it should be CGI/fast-CGI.

Answer (score 0):

**This error is usually related with the permissions/ownership issue**.

suPHP requires that the files are owned by the user name, and suExec requires that they are executed from the correct home folder.

Permissions on php files should also be set to `644` (-rw-r-r-), folder permission must be `755`.

**How to change ownership on the files and folders**

Go to CWP.admin Left Menu –> User Accounts — > Fix Permissions and select user.

Apache Logs are in: `/usr/local/apache/logs/`

http://wiki.centos-webpanel.com/500-internal-server-error